# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 Validate Token and Refresh token Implementation in .Net core 3.1

Tags: access-token, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm very new to the Identity and we're using Itfoxtec-identity-Saml2 in our Application which is very developer friendly.
I'm able to retrieve the Token using the customized Implementation for **GetToken(samlAssertionAttributes)**.
Could someone please help me with how to **Validate the token** and if the token time exceeds , get a **refresh token**.

Comment: Anders Revsgaard

Answer (score 1):

First, SAML 2.0 do not support refresh token like OAuth 2.0.

You can se how the SAML 2.0 Authn response is validated in the TestWebAppCore sample, in the [AssertionConsumerService](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L48) method.